# Как считывать QListWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qlistwidget

Я хочу написать что-то на подобии музыкального плеера, где при выборе *mp3* в списке она будет проигрываться. 
Но, пока, я даже не дошёл до того чтобы при выборе элемента в консоль писалось `click`.

Помогите сделать обработку нажатий в QListWidget.

Визуал делал с помощью *Qt Disigner*.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


def clicked():     #Функция которая должна вызываться при выборе элемента из списка(можно не обращать внимание.)
    print("click")


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 402)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.182, y1:0.102409, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0.113636 rgba(0, 62, 79, 147), stop:0.306818 rgba(28, 14, 68, 156));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-130, -40, 1031, 491))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("2HYI.gif"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 310, 641, 80))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget) #Начиная отсюда list
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 121, 311))
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("font: 75 italic 8pt \"MS Sans Serif\";\n"
"color: rgb(121, 92, 121);")
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roman")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item) 
        #сюда я пытался привязать clicked и connect
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow): 
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item=self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", 'w'))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)

#сюда тоже

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вам нужно обработать нажатие на один из элементов в listwidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*. Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

> void QListWidget::**`itemClicked`**(QListWidgetItem *item)
>
> Этот сигнал излучается с указанным элементом при нажатии кнопки мыши
> на элементе в виджете.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 402)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.182, y1:0.102409, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0.113636 rgba(0, 62, 79, 147), stop:0.306818 rgba(28, 14, 68, 156));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-130, -40, 1031, 491))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("2HYI.gif"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 310, 641, 80))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget) #Начиная отсюда list
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 121, 311))
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("font: 75 italic 8pt \"MS Sans Serif\";\n"
"color: rgb(121, 92, 121);")
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roman")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
     
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow): 
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item=self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", 'w'))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                     
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.myList = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', ]
        self.listWidget.addItems(self.myList)
        
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        
    def onClicked(self, item): 
        print(f'\nitem: {item}') #
        print(f'item.text: {item.text()}') #
      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно ссылки на гайды и документации, конечно если так можно по правилам форума. Хочу подтянуть свои знания в Qt.

Comment: @lofo пожалуйста https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html

Answer (score 0):

> В общем мне нужно сделать обработку нажатий в листе

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией `itemClicked`.

Например, обработку нажатия на элемент из  `listWidget` можно привязать к функции `clicked`, только саму функцию добавьте в класс `Ui_MainWindow`:

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    . . . 
    self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.clicked)

def clicked(self, item):
    print(f'clicked {item}')
```

Comment: Простите но я очень слабый в этой теме, мне нужны полные примеры. Я в курсе об itemClicked но я не знаю что куда привязывать.